# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') after using df.drop command

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I understand that the error is because I have `NaN` values in my csv, but I have the command `df.dropna` in many places in my code, so I don't understand why it is interpreting the code as still having `NaN` values.

Now it is making me write more because of my long code, you can just ignore this, it is gibberish, please refer to the above sentence for my question, I greatly appreciate your help for helping me solve it, thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from collections import Counter
from sklearn import svm, model_selection as cross_validation, neighbors
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, VotingClassifier

def process_data_for_lables(ticker):
    hm_days = 7
    df = pd.read_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv', index_col=0)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    tickers = df.columns.values.tolist()
    df.fillna(0)

    for i in range (1,hm_days+1):
        df['{}_{}d'.format(ticker, i)] = (df[ticker].shift(-i)-df[ticker])/ df[ticker]

    df.fillna(0)
    return tickers, df
#process_data_for_lables('XOM')

def buy_sell_hold(*args):
    cols = [c for c in args]
    requirement = 0.02
    for col in cols:
        if col > requirement:
            return 1
        if col < -requirement:
            return-1
    return 0

def extract_featuresets(ticker):
    tickers, df = process_data_for_lables(ticker)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    df['{}_target'.format(ticker)] = list(map(buy_sell_hold, 
                                              df['{}_1d'.format(ticker)], 
                                              df['{}_2d'.format(ticker)],
                                              df['{}_3d'.format(ticker)], 
                                              df['{}_4d'.format(ticker)], 
                                              df['{}_5d'.format(ticker)], 
                                              df['{}_6d'.format(ticker)], 
                                              df['{}_7d'.format(ticker)]))

    vals = df['{}_target'.format(ticker)].values.tolist()
    str_vals = [str(i) for i in vals]
    print('Data spread:', Counter(str_vals))
    df.fillna(0)

    df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)

    df_vals = df[[ticker for ticker in tickers]].pct_change()
    df_vals = df_vals.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0)
    df_vals.fillna(0)

    X = df_vals.values
    y = df['{}_target'.format(ticker)].values
    np.nan_to_num(X)
    return X, y, df
#extract_featuresets('XOM')  

def do_ml(ticker):

    X, y, df = extract_featuresets(ticker)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X,
                                                                    y,
                                                                    test_size = 0.25)
    clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    confidence = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
    predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
    print('Predicted spread:', Counter(predictions))

    return confidence

do_ml('BAC')
```

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
>   dtype('float64').

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of places where the NaNs might be propagated. You could try:

```
df_vals = df_vals.fillna(0)
...
X = np.nan_to_num(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

**The first step in solving any problem is recognizing there is one.**

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Are you sure that your processed dataframe contains NaN only? There might be the case where you have infinity.
You can check your dataframe, whether it contains infinity or NaN. 
To check for NaN present or not, use:

```
df.isnull().any().any()
```

If the output is true, you still have NaN present.

To check for infinity present or not, use:

```
df.isinfinity().any().any()
```

If you find any of the command's output to be true, then perhaps you should try removing that type of values from the dataframe. Else, please make sure all the values are in range of dtype float64.

Please share your findings!

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a very large file, and I have many like it, so it would be much better to have the program drop theses values instead of me manually going in.